# how to add component in box layout on north of other and make them all anchor on south?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, boxlayout

I try to make a very mini game.

I have one `JPanel`, it uses a `BoxLayout.Y_AXIS` that contains three `JLabel` (name of JLabels = 1,2,3)
I need a component inside that panel to anchor on South (so I use glue)

The view result will be like this:

---

1

2

3

---

Then I have a `JButton`.
If the user clicks the button, that `JPanel` adds a new `JLabel` (name of JLabel = neww)

Here is the view result:

---

1

2

3

neww

---

but I need something like this:

---

neww

1

2

3

---

how should I do?

Is it possible to handle it with `BoxLayout`?

Here is what I have tried:

```
public class help extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
JButton insert = new JButton("insert");
JLabel a = new JLabel("1");
JLabel b = new JLabel("2");
JLabel c = new JLabel("3");
public help()  {
    setSize(300, 200);
    getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250,150));
    getContentPane().add(insert, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    insert.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,50));
    insert.addActionListener(this);
    panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    panel.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
    panel.add(a);
    panel.add(b);
    panel.add(c);

    setVisible(true);
}

public static void main (String[]args){
   new help();
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    panel.add(new JLabel("NEW"));
    panel.revalidate();
    panel.repaint();
}
```

}

Thanks a lot for any kind of help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a version of the `add()` method that uses an index parameter.  Since you want to add it after the glue, use 1.

```
panel.add(new JLabel("NEW"), 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add another `JPanel` in the `BorderLayout.NORTH` position and add to that panel instead. You can use a `BoxLayout` for that panel also.

Note, no need to set the layout for your `JFrame`, as `BorderLayout` is the default layout for this container. Also, no point setting the preferred size of the panel as the `BorderLayout` will disregard this.

Comment: i can't.. cuz later there will many action to add and remove many of  jlabel.. so it will more complicated if i do that way... 
thanks a lot for correcting..