# Reordering elements in BoxLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout, boxlayout

I have a BoxLayout (`Y_AXIS`) with some (`FlowLayout`) elements already added like so:

```
element1> ================= <element1
element2> ================= <element2
element3> ================= <element3
```

Just wondering if there is a simple way to swap these elements positions in the layout. i.e. I might want to move element3 up and element2 down.

Is there anything like:

```
element3.setPosition(element2,ABOVE);
```

Thanks

EDIT: found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13167669/how-to-add-component-in-box-layout-on-north-of-other-and-make-them-all-anchor-on) solution. Gonna give it a go now

Comment: Try taking a look at [`Container#setComponentZOrder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#setComponentZOrder%28java.awt.Component,%20int%29)

Comment: @MadProgrammer, nice suggestion, sounds like an answer to me.

Comment: That looks good @MadProgrammer. Will give it a shot now. Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could consider using [`Container#setComponentZOrder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#setComponentZOrder%28java.awt.Component,%20int%29)

This will allow you to change the order in which components appear in the container (physically changing the order in which they are rendered and laid out)

```
int index = getComponentZOrder(element3);
setComponentZOrder(element3, --index);
```

Just beware, you can't set the zorder below `0` or above `getComponentCount() - 1`

Comment: +1, nice suggestion, the remove/add is done in one statement, just by changing the ZOrder.

Comment: Great Answer! works great. was not aware of this. Thanks

Comment: @user1270235 It's kinda funky but gets the job done ;)

Comment: @user1270235, I hope you read the API to actually understand what this method does because it is just a byproduct of the way Swing paints components that this happens to work. The ZOrder is actually used to control the "stacking of components" on top of one another.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there anything like...

You can make your own method to do that by using:

```
panel.remove(...);
panel.add(...);
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```

Cehck out the `Container` API for more details about those methods.

Comment: but the problem there is that it still just adds them to the bottom of the list. I would have to replace all of the elements within the two "moving" panels which would probably get a but messy..

Comment: @user1270235, as I said please read the API. There is more than one method signature for the add(...) method. The `add(component, int)` method allows you to specify the insertion position of the component. Having said that, madprogrammer's suggestion to use the ZOrder would be easier.